# Best practice for measurements relative to screen size, on mobile devices?

Tags: css

What unit or approach is best (or at least good!) practice for using measurements relative to screen size? I'm constraining this question to mobile devices, which I suspect may affect the answers. I'd thus wrap the styles inside `@media (hover:none), (hover:on-demand) { }`.

Answer (score 5):

> *[...] measurements relative to screen size*

For elements at the top level within `<body>` you can use `%`.

But in many cases I'd be inclined to use **viewport units**:

- `vw` - 1% of the *viewport width*
- `vh` - 1% of the *viewport height*
- `vmax` - equal to 1% of whichever is larger, *viewport width* or *viewport height*
- `vmin` - equal to 1% of whichever is smaller, *viewport width* or *viewport height*

---

**Further Reading:**

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/length#Viewport-percentage_lengths

Comment: One thing that's slightly bad about `vw` is that if there's a scrollbar then the box will ignore it, leaving horizontal and vertical scrolling. But `vh` always works fine.

Comment: Agreed, @Sven - `100vw` and `100%` of `<body>` give different results depending on what type of scrollbar you're dealing with - a touchscreen style scrollbar or a desktop window viewport style scrollbar. This is consistently a pain, but it won't be resolved until we have OS-agnostic scrollbars.